# SQLite elements in CREATE VIEW duplicating

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-view

This is my view which puts together columns from 3 tables

```
        db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW " + viewComps +
            " AS SELECT " + COMPANY + "." + colCompID + " AS _id," +
            " " + ACCOUNTS + "." + colName + "," +
            " " + COMPANY + "." + colCompClass + "," +
            " " + PAYMENTS + "." + colGroupID + "," +
            " " + PAYMENTS + "." + colPayDue + "," +
            " " + PAYMENTS + "." + colDateDue + "" +
            " FROM " + PAYMENTS + ", " + COMPANY +
            " JOIN " + ACCOUNTS + " ON " + PAYMENTS + "." + colGroupID + " = " + ACCOUNTS + "." + colID );
```

**PROBLEM**

1. I have 3 companies A, B and C
2. Acc 1 is assigned to A, 1 Acc = 1 Company ONLY
3. Acc 1 is inserted and assigned to A, problem is even if I assign it to A it will be duplicated for B and C as well.

The Result:

```
  Acc 1 | Company A | Payment | Date
  Acc 1 | Company B | Payment | Date
  Acc 1 | Company C | Payment | Date
```

What it should be :

```
  Acc 1 | Company A | Payment | Date
```

Every other account I insert into the database does the same and results in my companies containing a duplicate of all the accounts irregardless of which company the account is assigned to.

**QUESTION**

What am I doing wrong with my VIEW? I don't understand why it duplicates all the entries putting a copy of each account in each company. Can someone show me where my mistake is? I'm fairly new to this and could use a few pointers in this area. I'm fairly confident it's just a problem with this view as I have another activity that displays accounts based on company and it all works fine there at least.

I'll leave the 3 tables the VIEW references down below in case it's needed:

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + COMPANY + " (" + colCompID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            colCompClass + " TEXT)");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + ACCOUNTS + " (" + colID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            colName + " TEXT, " +
            colComp + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            colAmount + " INTEGER, " +
            colPurpose + " TEXT, " +
            colTerms + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            colPeriod + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            colBalance + " INTEGER, "+
            colStatus + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            colDate + " TEXT, " +
            colEditDate + " TEXT, " +
            colRemarks + " TEXT, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + colComp + ") REFERENCES " + COMPANY + " (" + colCompID + " )" + "ON DELETE CASCADE," +
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + colTerms + ") REFERENCES " + TERMS + " (" + colTermsID + " )" + "ON DELETE CASCADE," +
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + colPeriod + ") REFERENCES " + PERIODS + " (" + colPeriodID + ") " + "ON DELETE CASCADE,"+
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + colStatus + ") REFERENCES " + STATUS + " (" + colStatusID + ") ON DELETE CASCADE);");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + PAYMENTS + " (" + colPayID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            colGroupID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            colPayBal + " TEXT, " +
            colInterest + " TEXT, " +
            colPayDue + " TEXT, " +
            colDateDue + " TEXT, " +
            colPayDate + " TEXT, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + colGroupID + ") REFERENCES " + ACCOUNTS + " (" + colID + ") ON DELETE CASCADE);");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform a join with no constraint, it produces a cartesian product between the two data sets -- each row from the left side is combined with each row of the right side, so two tables of size M and N respectively when joined will produce a result of size (M x N).

Your view query performs two joins. One join (ACCOUNTS) has a constraint that limits the size of the result set, but the other (COMPANY) does not. What this means is when you join PAYMENTS and COMPANY, you get an instance of every combination of payment and company. Supposing there's 3 of each, it yields this:

```
Company A | Payment 1
Company A | Payment 2
Company A | Payment 3
Company B | Payment 1
Company B | Payment 2
Company B | Payment 3
Company C | Payment 1
Company C | Payment 2
Company C | Payment 3
```

Your observation that you get duplicated accounts is, in my opinion, actually an observation that you have duplicated payments. The accounts are joined based on the payments, so it's really this first join that is producing incorrect results.

What you need is a join constraint for both joins. Looking at your schema, it seems like payments and accounts have a relationship, so I think the correct query would look like this:

```
CREATE VIEW viewComps AS
SELECT ACCOUNTS.colName, COMPANY.colCompId AS _id, COMPANY.colCompClass, PAYMENTS.colGroupID, PAYMENTS.colPayDue, PAYMENTS.colDateDue
FROM ACCOUNTS
JOIN COMPANY ON (COMPANY.colCompId = ACCOUNTS.colComp)
JOIN PAYMENTS ON (PAYMENTS.colGroupID = ACCOUNTS.colID);
```

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, it's well appreciated. Cheers :)